# ¿Cómo evitar que el snackbar de Android corte el texto de un mensaje largo?

Tags: android, notificaciones

Estoy mostrando una alerta con un `Snackbar` en android, sin embargo como el texto es un poco largo queda cortado con los "..." puntos. Aún acortando el mensaje cuando la aplicación se ejecuta en pantallas mas pequeñas pasará lo mismo. ¿Como puedo evitar esto? He estado probando con:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, length);
            snackbar.setAction(context.getResources().getString(R.string.btnAcept), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    action.doAction();
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
            AppCompatTextView textView = (AppCompatTextView) snackBarView.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsTextView = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            paramsTextView.height =  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            textView.setLayoutParams(paramsTextView);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 180;
            snackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
            snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Aumentar el número de lineas de texto en un Snackbar.

Puedes usar alguna de estas dos propiedades del `TextView` del `Snackbar` que son **[setMaxHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxHeight(int))** o **[setMaxLines()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines(int))**

Usando **[setMaxHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxHeight(int))** defines la altura en pixeles de tu TextView

```
textView.setMaxHeight(1000);
```

Usando **[setMaxLines()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines(int))** defines el número de lineas que acepta tu `TextView` :

```
textView.setMaxLines(10);
```

Este es un ejemplo en donde puedes definir cualquiera de las 2 propiedades:

```
String text =  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
// Create the Snackbar
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 // Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
 // Get the TextView
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
//Set max lines!
textView.setMaxLines(20);
//Set max Height!
//textView.setMaxHeight(1000);
snackbar.show();
```

para obtener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, android le pone por defecto al TextView que se muestra en el SnackBar una cantidad máxima de 2 líneas, esto queda resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
 Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
        AppCompatTextView textView = (AppCompatTextView) snackBarView.getChildAt(0);
        textView.setMaxLines(3);
        snackbar.show();
```